# Arquitetura CSS, alguém poderia me explicar?

Tags: css, css3

Estou aprendendo **CSS**, já li alguns artigos falando sobre boas maneiras de escrever o seu código, e que principalmente ajudaria no trabalho em equipe. Então e li siglas, como - **BEM, OCSS, SMACSS**. Então fiquei muito curioso, só que esse conteúdo em PT-BR é muito raso, pelo menos eu achei.

Comment: Nunca ouvi falar de nenhum deles, me paressem padrões criados mais recentemente, de qualquer modo não adianta aprender eles sem aprender o básico do CSS, aprenda o que são seletores, cascata, pseudo-elementos, pseudo-classes e propriedades. Aprenda CSS1, CSS2, e css3 (o 2 tem o 1 e o 3 tem o 2 e o 1). Padrões você só deve usar quando conhecer o CSS de verdade, eles serão desnecessários se esta começando.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concordo totalmente com o Guilherme Nascimento, mas, apesar de a pergunta ser um pouco ampla, como esse é um assunto muito pouco falado e eu, particularmente, o acho interessante, e entendo um pouco já que vi há algum tempo em um livro, vou discorrer para você e futuros usuários.

Vamos em uma ordem cronológica:

### OOCSS

O [*Object Oriented CSS*](http://pt.slideshare.net/stubbornella/object-oriented-css) (CSS Orientado  a Objetos) surgiu em 2009 com Nicole Sullivan, com o objetivo de trazer ao CSS alguns benefícios da Orientação a Objetos. Como consequência, traria também a não repetição de código, além de resolver alguns outros problemas:

- A dificuldade de tocar projetos de médio/grande porte; é preciso ser
  um expert para isso;
- O tamanho dos arquivos CSS é cada vez maior conforme o projeto evolui;
- Reúso de código quase inexistente (pessoas não confiam em código
  alheio);
- Código frágil (até o melhor código pode se perder quando um não expert
  mexe nele).

E desse problemas surgirem soluções que tornam o CSS **Modular** (combinável, reusável e extensível), **Leve**, **Rápido** (poucas requisições HTTP e tamanhos mínimos de arquivos), **Manutenível** (semântico e padronizado) e **Simplificado e acessível**.

#### E Como fazer isso?

Com dois princípios básicos:

- Separar estrutura e skin;
- Separar contêiner e conteúdo.

**Separar estrutura e skin** é o mesmo padronizar características visuais como "skins" (identidade visual)  separadas, que podem ser combinadas em vários "objetos" para conseguir-se uma extensa gama de variações visuais sem muito código. Por exemplo, backgrounds e estilos de borda são agrupadas em classes próprias preservando "a cara do site".

**Separar contêiner e conteúdo** não é nada mais que evitar que seus elementos de suas bilbiotecas de padrões devem de uma localização específica. "Idealmente, um objeto deve parecer-se igual, independentemente de onde estiver na página, ou mesmo se trocar de página."

#### Mas o que é esse tal de Objeto no CSS?

Não é nada mais do que *aquele* conjunto de elementos que você guarda para executar determinado papel (padrão) dentro da página. Sendo esse papel regidos pelas classes CSS que você atribui a cada elemento. Exemplo (bem simples):

**Objeto Data Table**

```
<div class="data"> <!-- wrapper do Data Table -->
    <table class="center"> <!-- Alinha horizontalmente no centro -->
        <tr class="left"> <!-- Texto à esquerda -->
            <th>Chave 1</th> 
            <td>ID1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="left"> <!-- Texto à esquerda -->
            <th>Chave 2</th>
            <td>ID2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

---

Agora eu tenho que ir, mas posteriormente continuarei com os outros tópicos...

---

Fontes:

- http://pt.slideshare.net/stubbornella/object-oriented-css
- https://tableless.com.br/oocss-smacss-bem-dry-css-afinal-como-escrever-css/
- https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki
- Livro CSS Eficiente Técnicas e ferramentas que fazem a diferença nos seus estilos